# How can I display and then delete a random string from a list?

Tags: python, list

I want to make a game of science bingo for my class. This code currently randomly picks an element from the list and displays it, but I don't know how to delete that value from the list so it is not randomly reprinted.

```
from random import randint
bingo=["H", "He", "C", "O"]
total=((len(bingo))-1)
while (total>0):
    finish=input("Bingo?")
    if (finish=="no"):
        a=randint(0,int(total))
        b=(bingo[int(a)])
        print (b)
```

Comment: You have to update `total` or your loop will run forever.

Comment: python has `random.choice` you could call `remove`; you could also `shuffle` and `pop`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to delete from your list.  Just shuffle it and iterate over it once.  It will be faster and you can reuse your original list.  So do `random.shuffle(bingo)` then iterate over `bingo`.

Here is how to incorporate this into your original code:

```
import random
bingo=["H", "He", "C", "O"]
random.shuffle(bingo)
for item in bingo:
    if input("Bingo?") == "no":
        print item
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading, use `del`:

```
del bingo[int(a)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this once you have a couple of options

1)  Use a random index and pop

```
import random

i = random.randrange(0, len(bingo))
elem = bingo.pop(i)  # removes and returns element
```

2) use random choice them remove

```
import random

elem = random.choice(bingo)
bingo.remove(elem)
```

If you want all of the elements in a random order, then you're better off just shuffling the list and then either iterating over it, or repeatedly calling `pop`

```
import random

random.shuffle(bingo)
for elem in bingo: # list is not shuffled
    ...
```

or

```
import random

random.shuffle(bingo)
while bingo:
    elem = bingo.pop()
    ...
```

Answer (score -1):

```
foo = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
from random import randrange
random_index = randrange(0,len(foo))
```

**For displaying:**

```
print foo[random_index]
```

**For deletion:**

```
foo = foo[:random_index] + foo[random_index+1 :]
```